# Remove xml tag notepad++ but leave text

Tags: xml, tags, notepad++

i have many xml subtitle to edit
this are only two lines of the source;

```
<Subtitle SpotNumber="28" TimeIn="00:02:29:072" TimeOut="00:02:33:031">
  <Text VAlign="bottom" VPosition="17">Text Random</Font></Text>
  <Text VAlign="bottom" VPosition="10">Text Random</Font></Text>
</Subtitle>
```

Remove only the second tag < /Font>

Destination:

```
<Subtitle SpotNumber="28" TimeIn="00:02:29:072" TimeOut="00:02:33:031">
  <Text VAlign="bottom" VPosition="17">Text Random</Font></Text>
  <Text VAlign="bottom" VPosition="10">Text Random</Text>
</Subtitle>
```

Comment: The XML is not **well-formed**.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky yes i know, but it's a long history

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

regex for notepad++ search and remove

```
VPosition="10">.*?\K</Font>
```